# GPU vRAM minimum requirements for multiple GPUs running a 70B Llama 2 model at 4 bits

Tags: llama-2, gpu

### Backround

I would like to run a **70B LLama 2** instance locally (not train, just run).

Naively this requires 140GB VRam.

**Quantized to 4 bits** this is roughly 35GB (on HF it's actually as low as 32GB).

**I'd like to run it on GPUs with less than 32GB** of memory.

My understanding is that this is **easiest done by splitting layers between GPUs**, so only some weights are needed in each GPU.

### My question is:

**How do I determine the smallest size for a GPUs vRam for a single layer in 70B Llama 2?**

### For Clarity

I understand that this may result in each GPU being used in sequence so it may not perform well as well as one might expect for single-inference.